# Скрипт определения работы магазина по времени

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Добрый день. На Facebook есть хорошая функция. Она позволяет отслеживать время работы магазина относительно времени пользователя. И соответственно писать "Открыт сейчас" или "откроется в понедельник в 8-00".

Как такое реализовать? Есть ли что-то похожее?

[Пример на Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/tilitestoby/)

Comment: А что у Вас не вышло? И приведите тут пример, по ссылке не ясно (без авторизации не видно).

Comment: Исправил ссылку. Под кнопкой "Позвонить" есть текст 

"Организатор мероприятий в Минск"

Открыто сейчас

Comment: И в чём у Вас проблема? Вычисляете разницу поясов, выясняете время пользователя (объект `Date` в помощь) и ставите надпись по итогам.

Answer (score 1):

Придумал вот такое решение. Дни и время (часы и минуты) храним в json.

```js
var utc_vendor = '+3';
var utc_user = '-1';
wt = {
"days": {
 "2": {"1":"1","2":"2","4":"4","6":"6"},
 "3": {"1":"1","3":"3","7":"7"}
},
"time_from_h": {
 "2": {"1":"8","2":"9","4":"8","6":"10"},
 "3": {"1":"8","3":"9","7":"8"}
},
"time_from_m": {
 "2": {"1":"00","2":"05","4":"30","6":"50"},
 "3": {"1":"10","3":"00","7":"10"}
},
"time_to_h": {
 "2": {"1":"21","2":"20","4":"22","6":"18"},
 "3": {"1":"19","3":"17","7":"19"}
},
"time_to_m": {
 "2": {"1":"30","2":"40","4":"40","6":"52"},
 "3": {"1":"59","3":"10","7":"40"}
}
};

var d = new Date();
var hours = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();
var w_day = [7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6][new Date(d).getDay()];
var wd_name = {"7": "воскресение", "1": "понедельник", "2": "вторник", "3": "среду", "4": "четверг", "5": "пятницу", "6": "субботу"};

function get_vendor_time_status(id) {
 var hv = 0;
if(wt.days[id]) {
 if(wt.days[id][w_day] && ((wt.time_from_h[id][w_day] < hours && hours < wt.time_to_h[id][w_day]) || ((wt.time_from_h[id][w_day] == hours && wt.time_from_m[id][w_day] <= minutes) || (hours == wt.time_to_h[id][w_day] && minutes <= wt.time_to_m[id][w_day])))) {
  alert('Сейчас работает');
 } else {
  if(w_day == 7) w_nd = 1;
  else w_nd = w_day + 1;

  for(i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
   if (wt.days[id][w_nd]) {
    if(w_nd == 2) {
     alert( 'Откроется во ' + wd_name[w_nd] + ' в ' + wt.time_from_h[id][w_nd] + ':' + wt.time_from_m[id][w_nd] + '.' );
    } else {
     alert( 'Откроется в ' + wd_name[w_nd] + ' в ' + wt.time_from_h[id][w_nd] + ':' + wt.time_from_m[id][w_nd] + '.' );
    }
    break;
   }
   if(w_nd == 7) w_nd = 1;
   else w_nd = w_nd + 1;
  }

 }
}
}
get_vendor_time_status(2);
```

1. Можно ли оптимизировать код?
2. Сейчас ситуация, когда все данные отображаются в одном часовом поясе.
   Я знаю часовой пояс продавца. Именно в нем он указывает время работы.
   Можно ли как-то корректировать время в зависимости от часового пояса продавца и часового пояса пользователя?